# How to get texture size limit in a program on Opengl?

Tags: opengl

I have a qt program, which use several VBOs,and two framebuffer objects in QOpenglWidget like this:

```
class PatternWidget: public QOpenGLWidget,protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core {...}
```

Here I don't initialize some resources like `Points`/`Tangents`/`tbo_depth`/`tbo_norm` because these data will be reset outside the widget class,so I choose to allocate or reallocate these resources in `paintGL()` function.

```
void PatternWidget::initializeGL(){
...
glGenBuffers(1, &Points);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Points);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &Tangents);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Tangents);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &tbo_radiance);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tbo_radiance);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_R32F, 100, 100, 32);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glGenTextures(1, &tbo_density);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tbo_density);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_R32F, 100, 100, 32);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glGenTextures(1, &tbo_depth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo_depth);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glGenTextures(1, &tbo_norm);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo_norm);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthFrame);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthFrame);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, tbo_depth, 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tbo_norm, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rb_colorPattern);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb_colorPattern);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rb_depthPattern);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb_depthPattern);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &patternFrame);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb_colorPattern);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb_depthPattern);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
}
```

In `paintGL`,I use several bool value to make sure when some resources not allocated in `initialGL()` will be set here only once,and when be reset outside this class,will also be reset only once.

```
void PatternWidget::paintGL(){
    if(!frameObjectUpdated){//frameObjectUpdated bool value,to make sure reset framebuffer only once
        resetFBO();
    }
    if(!bufferObjectUpdated){//bufferObjectUpdated same as frameObjectUpdated
        resetBO();
    }
    if(!crossTextureUpdated){//crossTextureUpdatedsame as frameObjectUpdated
        resetCrossData();
    }
    //render depth texture for shadow map   
    glUseProgram(shadowProgram);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, depthFrame);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ...//some basic matrix set
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, renderSize);
    //render pattern in framebuffer 
    glUseProgram(renderProgram);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
    ...//some basic matrix set
    glBindVertexArray(vao_render);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, renderSize);
    //copy framebuffer to default framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebufferObject());
    glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,winWid, winHei,0,0, winWid, winHei,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,GL_NEAREST);
}
```

Here are my reset functions,`setFrameSize`accept window width and height outside the class,then call `resetFBO` to reset framebuffer size, same way to call `resetRenderData` and `resetBO` to reset vbo.

```
void PatternWidget::setFrameSize(int w,int h){
    winWid = w;
    winHei = h;
    resetFBO();
}
void PatternWidget::resetFBO(){
    if(openGLInitialized){
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo_depth);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo_norm);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb_colorPattern);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_RGBA,winWid, winHei);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb_depthPattern);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, winWid, winHei);

        frameObjectUpdated = true;
    }
}

void PatternWidget::resetRenderData(QVector<vec4> *pnts, QVector<vec3> *t){
    points = pnts;
    tangents = t;
    resetBO();
}

void PatternWidget::resetBO(){
    if(openGLInitialized){
        renderSize = points->size();
        int nBytes = renderSize * sizeof(vec4);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bo_renderPoints);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,nBytes,&(*points)[0].x,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        nBytes = renderSize * sizeof(vec3);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bo_renderTangents);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,nBytes,&(*tangents)[0].x,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        nBytes = renderSize * sizeof(float);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bo_renderRotations);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,nBytes,&(*rotations)[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        bufferObjectUpdated = true;
    }
}
```

I find that if `Points` and `Tangents` are 75M big, then the size of `tbo_depth` and `tbo_norm` should be smaller than 1024 * 1024,because if the size is bigger than 1024,shadow map won't work. I also copy `tbo_norm` to default framebuffer by `glBlitFramebuffer`,there wont be anything if size bigger than 1024.If `Points` and `Tangents` are half size then `tbo_depth` and `tbo_norm` size can be 2048 * 2048. Is there any way that I can get the actual max size of texture on different condition?

Comment: How did you find out this limits? Your code is noowhere initializing the sizes of `tbo_depth` or `tbo_norm`. If there is a problem, then it's probably that you are running out of GPU memory, 75M entries with 7*sizeof(float) entries are ~2GB of data.

Comment: I use QOpengglWidget,and I have to initializing these gpu objects in `paintGL()` function.And what I said 75M is wrong, actully I mean `Points` size is about 2.4 million,so take 2.4 million * sizeof(float) * 7 are 75MB footprint.

Comment: 1) It's still not clear to me how you know that 1024*1024 is the maximum possible? Do you get any errors? Does anything crash? 2) You don't have to initialize textures in paintGL. That wouldn't make any sense since paintGL is called in for every frame. Why would you want to reinitialize the textures each frame? 3) When you are using Qt, then you need to provide a more complete example that shows exactly what you call and where you call it.

Comment: First, I use bigger size of `tbo_norm` and `tbo_depth` for shadow map, it won't work,. I shrink the size , it works again. Then I use `glBlitFramebuffer()` to check `tbo_norm`  in that framebuffer object, just as I thought. Second, I use several bool value to make sure initialize resources only once. Third, I will edit my quetion, thank you for your patience.

Comment: When you edit, please also explain what "doesn't work" means. Does it crash somewhere? Do you get any exceptions? Does glGetError return an error? What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating your context, you can check the max texture size like this:

```
int value;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &value);
std::cout << "Max texture: " << value << " x " << value << std::endl;
```

but be aware that this is specific to your driver (maybe your GPU as well).

EDIT:

Other things to check, even though you might already know:

- You don't seem to be setting `resetFBO(w,h)` in

:

```
PatternWidget::setFrameSize(int w,int h){
    winWid = w;
    winHei = h;
    resetFBO();
}
```

for example:

```
void PatternWidget::resetFBO(int w, int h){
    if(openGLInitialized){
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo_depth);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, w, h,...)
...
```

Which might be important, since drawing to the shadow map requires changing the viewport size:

`glViewport(0, 0, shadowMapResolution, shadowMapResolution);`

- `bo_renderRotations` looks uninitialized, but maybe you didn't include in the original snippet for brevity.
- You could check if 1024 is hard coded somewhere else, like in the shader.

Because, even though it looks like, its pretty unlikely that the size of the VBO is influencing the resolution of the shadow map texture.

Comment: I tried, the max size is 32768,but just like I said, if I use two vertex buffer objects, which take 75MB GPU memory, the max size if below 1024*1024.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the `glBufferData` and `glTexImage2D` calls? And it depends on what you mean by the  "shadow map won't work", whether it is a crash, or just not displaying correctly, because the second case is most likely an issue with the alignment of the data in the buffers.

Comment: It just not displaying correctly, and I have edit the `glBufferData` and `glTexImage2D` calls.

Comment: I've added some stuff to the answer, if you want to take a look.

Comment: I do hard coded the `glViewport(0,0,1024,1024)` for shadow map. I guess the most possible reason is some of my other programs have take part of GPU memory, so in this program there will be a limit to my texture size. My solution to this problem is set maximum size to 1024 * 1024.

Comment: @Chris: If you would be out of memory, you would either be getting exceptions or glGetError would report GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY.

Comment: @BDL I will check that, thanks.